# Simple Servlet doesn't work in eclipse, build folder is empty, throwing ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I don't know what's the problem with this simple Java Servlet.

Eclipse has generated the Servlet..

What's the problem?

I have this log:

```
Jul 15, 2013 7:34:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
Jul 15, 2013 7:34:16 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:servlet' did not find a matching property.
Jul 15, 2013 7:34:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 15, 2013 7:34:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 15, 2013 7:34:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 697 ms
Jul 15, 2013 7:34:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 15, 2013 7:34:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.40
Jul 15, 2013 7:34:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 15, 2013 7:34:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 15, 2013 7:34:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 379 ms
Jul 15, 2013 7:34:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet TicketServlet as unavailable
Jul 15, 2013 7:34:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet TicketServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: source.TicketServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Folder Structure:

```
servlet
  -- src
    --source
      --TicketServlet.java
  --WebContent
    --WEB-INF
      --web.xml
```

generated web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>servlet</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>TicketServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>TicketServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>source.TicketServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TicketServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TicketServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

TicketServlet:

```
package source;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class TicketServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    }
}
```

Comment: how do you deploy it?

Comment: Directly with Eclipse. I never had this problem before..

Comment: Check in your directory where it has compiled classes

Comment: the build folder is empty, normal if source.TicketServlet is not found, it cannot compile..

Comment: Which kind of Project are you using? **Dynamic or Simple Java Project** ??

Comment: Same problem, Dynamic java project.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the runtime libraries from your application server.

For example:

Go to project properties. Click Build Path, then the libraries tab. Click add library, then select Server Runtime. Select your server and click OK.

Answer (score 1):

First of all which kind of project are you using??? Any project will have a Java Build Path set.
To get to it..

> Go to Project and right click on it and select Properties. e.g XYZ Project
>   --->Right Click--->Properties

Under that Choose **Java Build Path** and select **Source** tab. where under the window you can find a Path Specifier **"Default Output Folder"** this should contain path of your **build** folder as seen in image.

[image: Properties window for project]

If it is not containing the path than you can go to browse and select the path for build folder.

Keep in Mind that all your servlet's classes should be here and it needed to be configured.

Hope it helps..
And feel free to comment if you need more help.